# Angular4, redirect before render view?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How to redirect before render view?

**This is my code:**

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {
  if (/* some condition*/) {
    window.history.back();
  }
}

//OR

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
}
```

The current codes is displaying view before redirect?

How to redirect before render view?

Answer (score 5):

You should implement [canActivate guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) to prevent view from rendering and in canActivate redirect where You want.

```
 canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
     if (condition) {
        this.navigate([somewhere]);
      }
      return true;
  }
```